# How to extract two values from the response based on some condition in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Trying to capture date (2021-06-27) & ID (001c) values with condition flag as false from the below response. Date & ID should be from same segment. Unable to fetch same set of values. For example, I need to extract 2021-06-27 & its corresponding ID value 001c. Kindly help in the expression or JSON extractor query

Response:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "Dates": {
            "2021-06-26": {
                "id": [
                    "d388"
                ],
                "Flag": false
            },
            "2021-06-27": {
                "id": [
                    "001c"
                ],
                "Flag": false
            },
            "2021-06-28": {
                "id": [
                    "004t"
                ],
                "Flag": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('id',  new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.Dates['2021-06-27'].get('id')[0])
   ```
3. Refer the extracted value as `${id}` where required

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I need to extract the date & its corresponding ID based on the condition Flag as False. How to implement this condition with the above suggestion ? Values need to be extracted - (2021-06-27 & 001c based on condition Flag as False) or (2021-06-26 & d388 based on condition Flag as False).